# Bash: Find a word in file and add text after it

Tags: bash, sed, manipulate

I'm trying to build my own bash script for installing LEMP (nginx mariadb php).
I've managed to pull it off but I got stuck at the part where I need to add the 'index.php' text
to the index line @ /etc/nginx/sites-avaliable/default.

I've tried with "sed" and got very close but not there yet.

```
sed '/\index.htm/i index.php' input /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

that was the closest I got

i also tried replacing the index.htm file like this :

```
sed 's/index.htm/index.php' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Thanks for the help! :)

Comment: Show what you tried with `sed` and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: sed  '/\index.htm/i index.php' input /etc/nginx/sites-available/default -- that was the closest I got

Comment: i also tried replacing the index.htm file like that :  sed 's/index.htm/index.php' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

Comment: Please edit the question with this information, don't put it in comments.

Comment: You need to redirect output with `> outputfile`

Comment: Why are you escaping the `i` in `index.htm`?

Comment: probably a typo, the i isn't there in the script.

Comment: can i output the file to the same name and 'overwrite' it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to replace in the input file, you have to use the `-i` option. Otherwise `sed` sends the output to stdout.

The `s` command requires a terminating delimiter.

```
sed -i 's/index.html/index.html index.php/' /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
```

Comment: Thank you! is there a way to append the index.php after the index.html instead of replacing it?

Comment: by the way the sed -i just replaced the 'htm' with php and left the 'l' (of html) so that didn't work :(

Comment: Change it to `index.html`.

Comment: What is actually in the original file? I assumed you knew what you wanted to replace, and just needed to know the correct syntax.

Comment: lol i can't. the index.html must be in this line and cannot be raplaced. i'm trying to add index.php after it or at least replace the index.htm file that comes after index.html

Comment: the line should look like this:
"index.html index.htm index.php;"